# numpy function to reorder along an axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there an easier way (np function) to achieve the following? `bb` is the output I'm looking for.

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.arange(4*4*3).reshape(4,4,3)
bb = np.stack((aa[:,:,2],aa[:,:,1],aa[:,:,0]),axis=2)
```

I don't think `np.roll` is applicable here, because it seems to shift sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use -1 as the step argument on last axis while indexing to create a reverse array along that axis:

```
In [10]: bb = aa[:,:,::-1]
```